# help solving "unsolvable" definite integral describing aerodynamic property

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I need some urgent help with this particular integral:

\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{b} \frac{r^3 \sqrt{1-\frac{r}{b}}}{\sqrt{1 + k^2 r^2}} dr
\end{equation}

where k and b are a constant.

This is an integral that helps describing the forces along an helicopter blade, and it would be amazing if I could find a solution to this integral, as it would solve my system of equations and allow me to size all parameters accordingly.

I tried to solve it first with my graphical calculator, then moved on to wolfram alpha, but none were able to write me a solution. I tried to solve it by hand, but it never ended, and I tried to prepare a numerical way to solve it, but had the problem that I couldnt pull out the k constant outside of the integral.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Cheers!

Comment: damn it, sorry, had a mistake. The numerator sqrt was written wrongly.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing to do is reduce the problem from one with two parameters ($b$ and $k$) to one with a single parameter, say $a=bk$, by the substitution $x=r/b$. Thus: $$\int_{0}^{b} \frac{r^3 \sqrt{1-r/b}}{\sqrt{1 + k^2 r^2}} \,\mathrm dr=b^4\!\!\int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^3 \sqrt{1-x}}{\sqrt{1-a^2x^2}}\,\mathrm dx.$$An alternative, slightly simpler-looking, form of this integral can be got by substituting $x=a^{-1}\sin\theta$, which yields $$\frac1{k^4\surd a}\int_0^{\arcsin a}\sqrt{a-\sin\theta}\,\mathrm d\theta.$$Any practical evaluation of such an integral requires numerical approximation, and the simplest way to do it is by a standard numerical integration method applied to the (single-parameter) integral for various appropriate numerical choices of the parameter $a$.

Comment: Do you mind writing out the formula for me? I am not really sure how you do your substitution.

Comment: @user3604362: I have done this.

Comment: Ah! I get it now! Thank you very much!

Comment: @user3604362: An alternative form now added.

Comment: this last integral has a quiete nice expression in terms of elliptic integrals....

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is going on (apparently you have had a typo in the post now corrected), but W|A actually does find a primitive:
[image: W|A integration]

Since you integrate from $0$ to $b$, just substitute $r=b$ and you are done.

Comment: well, the problem is that I am still left with integrals... the two elliptical integrals. And in all honesty, I have no idea what they mean nor even how to solve them.

Comment: Well, which form then would you prefer? You can have a series expansion I believe. The point is, it does not really get any much simpler. Although you can easily employ full-blown computer algebra systems like Maple or Mathematica to solve your engineering problem either symbolically, if you are lucky or smart, or numerically.

Answer (score 0):

I really do not know what you could be doing with this monster : using 
dbanet's answer, using integration bounds and simplifying you have $$
\int_{0}^{b} \frac{r^3 \sqrt{1-\frac{r}{b}}}{\sqrt{1 + k^2 r^2}} dr
=\frac{32}{315} b^4 \,
   _3F_2\left(\frac{1}{2},2,\frac{5}{2};\frac{11}{4},\frac{13}{4};-b^2 k^2\right)$$ where appears the generalized hypergeometric function.

If $kb$ is small, we can develop some expansions $$\, _3F_2\left(\frac{1}{2},2,\frac{5}{2};\frac{11}{4},\frac{13}{4};-x\right)=1-\frac{40 x}{143}+\frac{336 x^2}{2431}-\frac{3840 x^3}{46189}+\frac{5376
   x^4}{96577}-\frac{43008 x^5}{1077205}+O\left(x^6\right)$$

I wish you a lot of fun !

Back to serious, as John Bentin answered, I think that numerical methods would be the most appropriate approach.

Comment: just comprehension wise, what does the F mean?

Comment: A monster, as I wrote ! This is the notation for hypergeometric function.  You should enjoy http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeneralizedHypergeometricFunction.html. If I may ask, what do you want to do exactly ? Identify $k$ or what else ?

Comment: Well, I have two equations that describe the lift/drag distributions across a blade with constant lift and drag coefficient (so with optimal twist), with the two remaining unknowns k and b. Both of these equations though end up with that given integral. I was hoping that if I can solve this integral, I can finally end up knowing the result of k and b, which would be a huge step forward in my research. (It afterwards gets even harder when the lift coefficient are not constant, so a blade with non-optimal or no twist.)

Answer (score 0):

Note that if $r \ll 1$ we can use a taylor expansion to approximate the integral.

$$\frac{r^3 \sqrt{1-\frac{r}{b}}}{\sqrt{1 + k^2 r^2}} \sim r^3-\frac{r^4}{2b}-\left( \frac{1}{2}k^3 + \frac{1}{8b^2}\right)r^5$$

And so by integrating the right handside expression we get

$$
   \int_0^b \frac{r^3 \sqrt{1-\frac{r}{b}}}{\sqrt{1 + k^2 r^2}}\,\mathrm{d}r
\sim \frac{31}{240} b^4-\frac{1}{12} b^6 k^3
$$

For more accuracy just take more terms in the taylorexpansion and integrate. For 20 terms I get

$$
\begin{align*}
   \int_0^b \frac{r^3 \sqrt{1-\frac{r}{b}}}{\sqrt{1 + k^2 r^2}}\,\mathrm{d}r
& \sim 
{\frac {281614163389}{2705829396480}}\,{b}^{4}-{\frac {9156607}{
1693450240}}\,{b}^{14}{k}^{10}+{\frac {2395393}{508035072}}\,{b}^{16}{
k}^{12} \\ & - {\frac {89947}{18677760}}\,{b}^{18}{k}^{14} + {\frac {1287}{
131072}}\,{b}^{20}{k}^{16}+{\frac {483206531}{70447529984}}\,{b}^{12}{
k}^{8} \\ & -{\frac {72093703351}{2418335023104}}\,{b}^{6}{k}^{2}+{\frac {
74547724921}{4894249451520}}\,{b}^{8}{k}^{4}-{\frac {52063283099}{
5424459808768}}\,{b}^{10}{k}^{6} \end{align*}
$$

Which should be accurate for $bk < 1$.